# Android ImageView adds white space around image (tried fixes on here an no luck)

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview

I am creating an android start screen which has an image inside an ImageView.

The image i have put inside the image view is 75x75 pixels without any white space (see below).

I have attempted to set the background to transparent/black/remove layout padding and still no luck.

Image i am using:

[image: image i am using there is no background]

the results of my xml  file for activity_start_screen.xml

[image: start screen result]

Here is my current xml for the screen in question, i am capable in Java but first time doing android so i don't know all the tips and tricks just yet!

XML:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/startScreenRelLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context=".StartScreen" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startCreateWalkButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/logoImageView"
        android:text="@string/startCreateButtonText" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startEditWalkButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/startCreateWalkButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/startEditButtonText" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logoImageView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="114dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logoText"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

There is no code in the java file just yet, im just creating the layout or should i do image adding/color setting using java code.

the color black is set as #000000 so it is indeed black

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.png` images instead other format.

Comment: well i feel stupid, the original was .png when i exported it i forgot to save as png. thanks